# createAsyncThunk function returns userId undefined data attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch `appointment` data from my rails-api backend using the createAsyncThunk function. When I

```
console.log('appointmentDate', appointmentDate);
console.log('doctorId', doctorId);
console.log('userId', userId);
```

After clicking the submit button to create a new appointment; I get:

```
appointmentDate => 2021-07-30 which is fine
doctorId => 2 which is also fine.
userId => undefined which is not what I'm expecting. I expected a number just like doctorId
```

I have tested the backend with postman and everything is fine. And since I can't fetch the correct data. I can't create an `appointment` when I submit the `form`

This is how I'm destructuring the `user` state before adding it to the `postAppointment` action creator for dispatch

```
const { data: userData } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
const { userId } = userData;
since `user_Id` is part of the `user` state in my `store`. I can destructure it as above and add it to my `dispatch`.
```

And this is how I'm dispatching it inside the `NewAppointment` component

```
dispatch(postAppointments({ userId, doctorId, appointmentDate }))
      .then(() => {
        setSuccessful(true);
        alert.show('Appointment created', {
          type: 'success',
          timeout: 2000,
        });
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        setSuccessful(false);
      });
```

I don't know what I'm missing with the `user` destructuring and dispatching the `action creator`?

Here are the other codes

src/redux/appointmentsSlice

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import API from '../api/api';

export const postAppointments = createAsyncThunk(
  'appointments/postAppointments',
  async (
    {
      userId, appointmentDate, doctorId,
    },
  ) => {
    console.log('appointmentDate', appointmentDate);
    console.log('doctorId', doctorId);
    console.log('userId', userId);
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/users/${userId}/appointments`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        appointmentDate,
        doctorId,
        userId,
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('appointmentsData', data);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(data.failure);
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.jwt);
    console.log('localstorageData', data);

    return data;
  },
);

export const appointmentsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'appointments',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    data: [],
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [postAppointments.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [postAppointments.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [postAppointments.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export default appointmentsSlice.reducer;
```

src/components/NewAppointment

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { postAppointments } from '../redux/appointmentsSlice';
import { getDoctors } from '../redux/doctorsSlice';

const NewAppointment = () => {
  const [appointmentDate, setAppointmentDate] = useState('');
  const [doctorId, setDoctorId] = useState('');
  const [successful, setSuccessful] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { data: userData } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { userId } = userData;
  console.log('userData', userData);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data, error } = useSelector((state) => state.doctors);
  console.log('data', data);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === null && userData) {
      dispatch(getDoctors())
        .then(() => {
          loading(false);
        })
        .catch(() => {
        //   setError('Unable to get doctors list');
        });
    }
  }, [data, dispatch]);

  const onChangeDoctorId = (e) => {
    const doctorId = e.target.value;
    setDoctorId(doctorId);
    console.log('doctorUnchange', doctorId);
  };

  const onChangeAppointmentDate = (e) => {
    const appointmentDate = e.target.value;
    setAppointmentDate(appointmentDate);
    console.log('apptntmentonchange', appointmentDate);
  };

  const handleBooking = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSuccessful(false);

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
    dispatch(postAppointments({ userId, doctorId, appointmentDate }))
      .then(() => {
        setSuccessful(true);
        alert.show('Appointment created', {
          type: 'success',
          timeout: 2000,
        });
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        setSuccessful(false);
      });
  };

  console.log('data now', data);
  const options = data && (
    data.map((doctor) => (
      <option
        key={doctor.id}
        value={doctor.id}
      >
        {doctor.name}
      </option>
    ))
  );

  if (!userData) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
  if (successful) {
    return <Redirect to="/appointments" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="card card-container">
        <form onSubmit={handleBooking}>
          { !successful && (
          <div>
            <div className="form-group create">
              <label htmlFor="appointmentDate" className="control-label">
                Appointment Date
                <input
                  type="date"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="appointmentDate"
                  id="appointmentDate"
                  required
                  value={appointmentDate}
                  onChange={onChangeAppointmentDate}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group create">
              <label htmlFor="doctorId">
                Select from list:
                <select className="form-control" id="doctorId" onChange={onChangeDoctorId} value={doctorId}>
                  {loading ? <option>Loading..</option> : options }
                </select>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group create">
              <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled={loading} type="submit">
                {loading && (
                <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" />
                )}
                <span>Book</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          )}
          {error && (
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className={successful ? 'alert alert-success' : 'alert alert-danger'} role="alert">
              {error}
            </div>
          </div>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default NewAppointment;
```

And the `API url` returns undefined for the `userId variable` as shown below

```
POST https://agile-escarpment-87534.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/undefined/appointments 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my first project using `createAsyncThunk` and still trying to understand how it works. I have also checked similar posts, but none solved my issue.
Any support or constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: Did you check whether `userId` inside `userData` is actually property set?

Comment: @Kelvin, If I get your question. `user_id ` is part of the userData object property and takes values such as 1,2,3, etc . I get this from the console userData        {username: "test_user", user_id: 1, jwt: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.7kO493fIYp8enGgfwPpWpZfc5BwmrZNx6arNGZWtS94"}. Once I'm login

Comment: There's your problem. It logs `user_id` but your code uses `userId´.

Comment: But JavaScripts allows camel case `userId` and not underscore `user_id`. So how do I go about this?

Comment: Using `user_id` is allowed? It allows underscores and even dollar signs. _I think it even accepts any unicode character that isn't a special (ANSII/JS) character._ You can definitely do `userData.user_id`. And even if that wasn't possible, you can use `userData['user_id']` to index by any string, along as  you escape every `'` and ```\``` with `\'` and ```\\```.

Comment: When I try it the way you said like this: `dispatch(postAppointments({userData.user_id, doctorId, appointmentDate}))`. eslint alert me with this error: error  Parse errors in imported module '../components/NewAppointment': Unexpected token, expected "," (47:39) (47:39)  import/no-named-as-default-member.

Comment: what about `dispatch(postAppointments({userData['user_id'], doctorId, appointmentDate}))`?

Comment: That's a weird error. It's ESLint so perhaps a bug in the linter. But `.user_id` is valid JS.

Comment: @devtye, I get the same error. I guess because it's inside an object `{}`

Comment: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-named-as-default-member.md

Comment: that's error you are getting

Comment: @Kelvin. Yes it's Eslint

Comment: If the rule annoys you, you can disable it. I'm not sure why it even gets triggered here, since it's supposed to only trigger for imports.

Comment: another option is you try to write another selector just to select the `user_id` and bring that into the componet.

Comment: can you do `const { user_id } = userData;`?

Comment: @devtye, after making the suggested change, the `user_id` is returning the right value in the console. However, the `API URL` is still returning the `404` error not found: POST-https://agile-escarpment-87534.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/4/appointments 404 (Not Found). I don't know why???

Comment: checked here with a small test... works https://jsfiddle.net/15pzjrbv/

Comment: hmm something must be still wrong, it looks like it can't locate your endpoint

Comment: @ devtye, Yes, I guess that's where the issues are. Let me troubleshoot further...

Comment: do have to be logged into access the endpoint?

Comment: the reason I asked is ... you said that you were able to make the same request on PostMan. What step did you have to do to make that request? Method Type, Special Header such as tokens, base URLs, options ....these things could make the difference between hitting it or getting 404

Comment: @devtye, In postman after creating  a `user`. I copied the generated token to the authorization section. I then use this Heroku link : `https://agile-escarpment-87534.herokuapp.com/api/v1/appointments` with this body: {
  "appointment_date": "30/07/21",
  "doctor_id": 1,
  "user_id": 1  
} to create the appointments. But using this same link like so doesn't work inside the `createAsyncThunk`. Hence I had to use this: `${API}/users/${user_id}/appointments`. Where API= `https://agile-escarpment-87534.herokuapp.com/api/v1 ` which I'm importing. The return for me seems ok.

Comment: `POST https://agile-escarpment-87534.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/1/appointments`  404 (Not Found). But still has the 404 error. And I really can't figure out why???

Comment: Well, that might be your problem... You authorize your request in PostMan... I don't see you are doing the same thing in your code.

Comment: these are headers (token) that you must add to your thunk request.. not sure the syntax for it... but I believe that is what is missing.

Comment: @devtye, I believe that is where my problem lies. I will work around it and give feedback.

Comment: I think I can tell you how to solve this... what type of authorizing did you use in POST Man

Comment: Api Key, Basic Auth, Bearer Token or OAuth?

Comment: I'm working on a solution for you... you did say it was jwt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need the token from here

```js
  const { user_id, jwt } = userData;
```

add the extracted token from the `userData` to postAppointments

```js
dispatch(postAppointments({ user_id, doctor_id, appointment_date, jwt }))
      .then(() => {
        setSuccessful(true);
        alert.show('Appointment created', {
          type: 'success',
          timeout: 2000,
        });
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        setSuccessful(false);
      });
```

finally add the token to the fetch request

```js
export const postAppointments = createAsyncThunk(
  'appointments/postAppointments',
  async (
    {
      user_id, appointment_date, doctor_id, jwt
    },
  ) => {
    console.log('appointmentDate', appointment_date);
    console.log('doctor_id', doctor_id);
    console.log('user_id', user_id);
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/appointments`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        // this your missing header
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        appointment_date,
        doctor_id,
        user_id,
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('appointmentsData', data);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(data.failure);
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.jwt);
    console.log('localstorageData', data);

    return data;
  },
);
```

This is just a guess.. because I don't have actual code.

**UPDATE:**

Another way to write that fetch:

```js
fetch(`${API}/appointments`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    appointment_date,
    doctor_id,
    user_id,
  }),
}).then(response => {
  response.json();
}).then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
  localStorage.setItem('token', data.jwt);
}).catch((error) => {
  // request just fail
  throw new Error('Error:', error);
});
```

inspired by: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I didn't the new fetch code. you might have to test it out

Comment: I still get the `404` status error after implementing both methods. Here is my repl: `https://github.com/enaburekhan/doctors-booking-app/tree/feature` just in case you can create time to have a look.

Comment: there must be somthing I'm still missing on the request. Would it be possible to extract the curl from PostMan... it gives you all the detail about the request itself. `< / >` on right side of the request tab

Comment: This functionality is called the code snipet. -> https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: direction to find it

Comment: if you are down for some pair program ... I'm intrigued about the issue you are having:  tyefighter#6840 -> is my discord. Let's link up and see if we can figure it out together. I have time now

Comment: ok. Would you mind if I create a zoom link???  From postman:                               curl --location --request POST 'https://agile-escarpment-87534.herokuapp.com/api/v1/appointments' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyfQ.a_IJA12FDnbqwdbf4LxB7JQcW7i_mXjcjVwN6oAkPfk' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '
{
  "appointment_date": "30/07/21",
  "doctor_id": 1,
  "user_id": 1  
}'

Comment: I can work with zoom. send me the link. I think I found your issue, but is best I show you

Comment: Discord invite link: https://discord.gg/xwXneeX2bF.  Zoom link: https://microverse.zoom.us/j/96481647280?pwd=RGdZcm9SdzNucGpuV1BaeHM5eFl1Zz09